# How to change variable in ReactJS after deployment

Tags: reactjs

I have a static React app that I have deployed online using Host Gator. I want to be able to change a variable to true or false to activate or deactivate a certain feature without having to rebuild and re-upload my app.
What is the best way to achieve this goal? 
My initial thoughts were to use environmental variables, but I'm not really sure how to change those in host gator. I had also thought about just using a database like Firebase and fetching the value from there. Is there a more effective way that I'm not thinking of?

Comment: read url params? like `?useFeature=true` and read it inside the app

Answer (score 0):

If you want the value to persist you will need to fetch it from a database or a file. You can make a node server which flips the value in a file from true to false when you hit a certain endpoint. Then do a fetch() in your react app to fetch the current value from the file on your server.

Otherwise use a url parameter like Sagiv mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

So by 'static' I assume that means you're not building your app, correct?  Normally this is built into the build script.

You can make a dev.config.js file and a prod.config.js, and then require in a file that checks for `localhost` in the URL to decide which config file to load.